# How to stop a frame breaker?

Tags: iframe, framebusting

I'm trying to iframe a website that has implemented a framebreaker code. This is the URL:

http://bit.ly/P39Tev

Do you know any way to make it so that it doesn't break out of frame? I've tried almost every framebreaker buster codes but none have worked correctly, or stopped the website from loading completely.

I would really appreciate a solution for this.

---

Edit:

Here is my iframe code:

```
<IFRAME SRC='bit.ly/P39Tev'; SCROLLING='no' WIDTH='1' HEIGHT='1' FRAMEBORDER='no'></IFRAME>
```

Comment: can we see your html code that you're using to display the iframe?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, but I would like to finish what I'm working on. It's ok if you don't want to help me, but perhaps another user here could have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that this website is breaking out of the iframe, it is that the iframe is redirecting the whole page to the actual website. Check the URL bar as you pull up the page, you will see it. This is how I fixed it:

```
<IFRAME  src='http://bit.ly/P39Tev' sandbox='' scrolling='no' width='100' height='100' frameborder='yes'></IFRAME>
```

This will prevent the page from redirecting the parent:

```
sandbox=''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add SANDBOX to the iframe tag, you can leave it blank or you can put it this way:

```
<IFRAME SRC='bit.ly/P39Tev'; SCROLLING='no' WIDTH='1' HEIGHT='1' FRAMEBORDER='no' SANDBOX='allow-scripts'></IFRAME>
```

to make bit.ly able to use javascript. If you don't know if the frame could sometime need to use forms, you can use:

```
<IFRAME SRC='bit.ly/P39Tev'; SCROLLING='no' WIDTH='1' HEIGHT='1' FRAMEBORDER='no' SANDBOX='allow-scripts allow-forms'></IFRAME>
```